Is there a way to dynamically make functions public in the child class?
I have an interface class that is used for API, and most of the functions are protected.
So when I do unit test on these, I normally create a child test class from the target class I want to test, and overwrite the visibility of the parent class' functions for testing.
My question is if there is a way to simplify this by doing this dynamically, which would simplify the maintenance? Let's say in the tester class' constructor - or any other way?

I think you need to read up on dependency injection.

Although I voted to close as a duplicate, I just want to say that while reading through that thread you will see two very distinct opinions, one is that protected/private methods should only be tested indirectly through public methods, while the other is that all code should be tested. I would encourage you to expand all of the comments to see the full discussions that took place, and to weigh the upvotes on various comments accordingly.
